# Let P(X=3)=0.4 and P(Y=2)=0.5. Find P(X=3,Y=2).

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $P(X=3)=0.4$ and $P(Y=2)=0.5$. I need to find $P(X=3,Y=2)$.

I'm thinking that I ought to just multiply the two probabilities: $P(X=3) \times P(Y=2)$ to get $0.4 \times 0.5 = 0.2$, but is this correct?

If not, how do I go about finding this? There is a chance that it is uncomputable.

**Edit**: They are not independent.

Both X and Y are random variables.

Comment: If you assume that X and Y are independent random variables, then your answer is correct. Otherwise, we would need a bit more information to answer your question.

Comment: The answer can be anything between 0.4 and zero if independence is not assumed.

Comment: I checked, and they are not independent.

Comment: @JeremyQuick: How do they depend on each other?

Comment: For instance, do you know the likelihood of Y given X. If so, you could compute $P(X \cap Y)=P(Y|X)P(X)$. But without any further information, it is difficult to recover the joint probability from the marginals.

Comment: I edited the question with additional information, such as X and Y are random variables and there may be no computable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that X and Y are independent random variables, then your answer is correct. Otherwise, we would need a bit more information to answer your question.